# Regex from C# to PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have this code running with C#.

```
var phrase = "// Hi++    My name's Jon'ss and .. ''c and d''ef.";
            var phraseCompressed = string.Empty;

            var wordRegex = new Regex(@"(\W*)(\w+)(\W*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var matches = wordRegex.Matches(phrase);

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                phraseCompressed += match.Groups[1].Value;
                phraseCompressed += "<" + match.Groups[2].Value + ">";
                phraseCompressed += match.Groups[3].Value;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Input  : " + phrase);
            Console.WriteLine("Output : " + phraseCompressed);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I ask for some help to translate this code to PHP.

It seems that Regex in PHP and C# are not the same.

Here a draft of solution (not working) :

```
$phrase = "// Hi++ My name's Jon'ss and .. ''c and d''ef.";
$phraseCompressed = "";
preg_match("/(.*)(w+)(.*)/", $phrase, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

I guess my regex is not OK in PHP.

Result expected :

```
Input : // Hi++    My name's Jon'ss and .. ''c and d''ef.
Output : // <Hi>++  <My> <name>'<s> <Jon>'<ss> <and> .. ''<c> <and> <d>''<ef>.
```

Kinds Regards,

Comment: First of all, `.*` is not the same as `\W*`. Besides, `\W` in C# regex is similar (but not equal to) `/\W*/u` in PHP (it is Unicode aware by default in .NET regex). Note that `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is redundant, `\w` matches both lower- and uppercase letters. The same pertains to `\w`, too. It seems you want to use `preg_replace('~\w+~u', '<$0>', $phrase)`

Comment: Why are not you using the same regex?

Comment: I tried but the same regex is not working or maybe i'm not using PHP correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't construct your regex properly. `w+` wouldn't be equal to `\w+`. The former matches one or more occurrences of letter `w` but latter matches word characters.

You also have a foreach loop in your C# code but missed it in PHP. Besides, `preg_match` returns one single match but `preg_match_all` returns all. You'd better try with `preg_replace`:

```
echo preg_replace('/\w+/', '<$0>', $phrase);
# // <Hi>++ <My> <name>'<s> <Jon>'<ss> <and> .. ''<c> <and> <d>''<ef>.
```

[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/licqT)